# Is there any DataProvider that support all the document types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm working on different document viewers eg: Docx,Txt and Rtf. For loading document I'm using Provider of specific document type according to the loading document. eg: for docx I'm using DocxFormatProvider and similar to other. Now I want to check such provider that support all the format. I want to use that provider that support to open or load all type of documents in WPF. Is there any provider exist whose behaviour is generic? I'm using RadRichTextBox not RichTextBox.